# routing errors when generating devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise, routes

when I run the server i get `uninitialized constant Customers::RegistrationController` error when i try to access the sign up page

here is my generated controller:

```
class Customers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
   def new
     super
   end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

here is all the routes for customers model:

```
new_customer_session GET    /customers/sign_in(.:format)          customers/sessions#new
            customer_session POST   /customers/sign_in(.:format)          customers/sessions#create
    destroy_customer_session DELETE /customers/sign_out(.:format)         customers/sessions#destroy
           customer_password POST   /customers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_customer_password GET    /customers/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_customer_password GET    /customers/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /customers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /customers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_customer_registration GET    /customers/cancel(.:format)           customers/registration#cancel
       customer_registration POST   /customers(.:format)                  customers/registration#create
   new_customer_registration GET    /customers/sign_up(.:format)          customers/registration#new
  edit_customer_registration GET    /customers/edit(.:format)             customers/registration#edit
                             PATCH  /customers(.:format)                  customers/registration#update
                             PUT    /customers(.:format)                  customers/registration#update
                             DELETE /customers(.:format)                  customers/registration#destroy
       customer_confirmation POST   /customers/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
   new_customer_confirmation GET    /customers/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                             GET    /customers/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
```

In my routing file I wrote this `devise_for :customers, :controllers => {  registrations: "customers/registration" }`

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, The routes are automatically generated when I generate models

[image]

Comment: What's the path to the registrations_controller?

Comment: is your Customers::RegistrationsController in a customers subdirectory in app/controllers or directly in app/controllers ?

Comment: Are you still struggling ?

Comment: yes, I'm still struggling, the Customers::RegistrationsController is inside the subdirectory named customers in app/controllers

Comment: This is probably a pluralisation error, try `devise_for :customers, :controllers => {  registrations: "customers/registrations" }` notice the `s` on the last registrations.

Comment: opps, thanks a lot for pointing that out, I dont know why I miss that

Comment: Is this a screenshot of your app/controllers directory ? Why is there no customers directory in it ?

Comment: sorry, for some reason I left out the customers directory when I took the screen shot